# Set ScrollView initial position swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to set my scrollview to the initial position, I'm trying with the contentoffset but I can not manage .. accessing the scrollview I always start from the bottom instead of from above .. some indication?

```
    var scrollView = UIScrollView().then {
    $0.alpha = 1
    $0.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //$0.isPagingEnabled = true
}
    self.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.activate([
        scrollView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
        scrollView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1),
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1),
        ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are using `UITextView` to show the text, instead of `UILabel`. TextView is for editing and hence will always start at the bottom.

Comment: Try in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        var bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: testoView.scrollView.contentSize.height - testoView.scrollView.bounds.size.height)
        self.testoView.scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
    }

Comment: I call the scrollview class in another file

Comment: You forgot to add super.viewWillAppear. Check the edited answer.

Comment: done as you told me, but it does not change anything. I begin to see everything from below

Comment: Oh you want to start at the top is it? That is the default. Why don't you make a small gif of what is happening in the value and add it to the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177004/discussion-between-rakesha-shastri-and-stefano).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you are likely better off using scrollToItem. an example would be like this:

```
    scrollView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: 10, section: 0), at: .centeredVertically, animated: false)
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: `scrollToItem` is not a `UIScrollView` method.